# Sudo arguments not working

Tags: sudo

Flags/arguments to sudo on my system aren't working.

```
peter@Sirius:~$ sudo -h
env: -h: No such file or directory
peter@Sirius:~$ sudo -u postgres
env: -u: No such file or directory
```

However, executables in sudo's path work fine.  My problem is not being removed from the admin group, or having a corrupted `/etc/sudoers` file.  Reinstalling sudo did not fix it, either -- https://askubuntu.com/a/46459/42720

Recently upgraded to 12.04; no other problems with the upgrade.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: probably, you have some config file that set sudo to a different binary.
To see where sudo "points" to, try `which sudo`

Comment: Points to /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: Cool; `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'`.  However, the alias is not in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, /root/.bashrc or /root/.profile.  Any ideas?

Comment: Found it with `find ~/ -size -20k -exec grep -H 'alias sudo.*' {} \;`; removed the line and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: in which file was the alias ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that the `sudo` you are running is probably different from the system's `sudo`.

This is (probably) a user configuration.

FIRST: Check if using `/usr/bin/sudo` works ok, to test that hipotesis.

IF IT DOES: Then either you are using another binary, or an alias

USING ANOTHER BINARY: Users can make different versions of system binaries to use (usually, they are just scripts). To check for that possibility, run `which sudo`. This will tell you the location of the `sudo` you are running. IF it says /usr/bin/sudo, then we exclude this possibility. If something else, that is probably the problem

USING AN ALIAS: an alias is a lightweight way to personalize commands. Instead of writing a binary, you make a small alteration, such as adding an option. This is done in configuration scripts for BASH, the program that reads the commands.
To check for that, type `alias` and see if sudo appears on the list. If it does, then this is probably the problem. Use `find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -size -20k -exec grep -H 'alias sudo.*' {} \;` to find the file that is setting up the alias (Some common guesses would be: ~/.bashrc ; ~/.bash_profile ;  ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile ).
If you cant find the file, use `find ~/ -size -20k -exec grep -H 'alias sudo.*' {} \;` instead, to look at all of your user's files. (this will take a *long* time)

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing.  It was an alias.  With the -20k argument it was actually very fast, even though my home directory is large.  Thanks